# Creating one unique array from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two arrays (Arr1, Arr2). I am trying to create a single array that has as many objects in it as Arr.1.length (an array of objects) where the format is:

```
[{name:Arr1[0], Arr2[0],Arr2[1]...etc}, {name:Arr1[1], Arr2[0],Arr2[1]...etc}..... etc]
```

Working with proprietary information so I cannot show the actual code. For the sake of simplicity we will examine the two arrays:

```
Arr1[1,2,3,4,5] 
Arr2[6,7,8,9]
```

The resulting array should be:

```
[{name:1,6:'',7:'',8:'',9:''},{name:2,6:'',7:'',8:'',9:''},{name:3,6:'',7:'',8:'',9:''},{name:4,6:'',7:'',8:'',9:''},{name:5,6:'',7:'',8:'',9:''}]
```

For the sake of simplicity just imagine the values above are strings where indicated.  I have used two for loops to manipulate two arrays.  Is there a method to call that would make this easier?

Comment: Please, add a real example of what you try to achieve... It isn't clear for me

Comment: The "resulting array" you expecting to get is not valid, you want an array of arrays?

Comment: I guess his looking for an array ob objects, but is not too clear... `[{1,6,7,8,9},{2,6,7,8,9},{3,6,7,8,9},{4,6,7,8,9},{5,6,7,8,9}]
`

Comment: Thought it was clear from my first sentence but yes.... and array of objects.  My apologies.

Comment: And what will be all the `key` names for those objects? You are only showing `name` key that will hold an element from `Arr1`.

Comment: But still, `{1,6,7,8,9}` is not well formatted. You need a key and a value to have an object

Comment: @JoseA.Ayllón edited to make it more clear my apologies.

Comment: @Shidersz hopefully edits make it more clear.  My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

One solution, is to use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over `Arr1` to map every `element` of this array to an object with a property `name` holding the `element`, then we use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over `Arr2` to add the other `keys` with empty string values.

```js
var Arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var Arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9];

var result = Arr1.map(function(name)
{
    let obj = {name}; // or "let obj = {name: name};" if no ES6 support.

    return Arr2.reduce(function(acc, curr)
    {
        acc[curr]= "";
        return acc;
    }, obj);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: this worked like a charm @Shidersz, thank you.  Is there a way you know how to check if a string (in this problem a number) is equal to any key on an object within that array?  So for example if I had 6 and wanted to analyze it with result[0] which is {name:1,6:'',7:'',8:'',9:''} and change the value of result[0].6 to "cat" if my variable is equal to that key how would I achieve that?  I looked into the .keys() method but I am not really looking to get an array back and put another step in the process if possible not to.

Comment: @D-Man I don't quite understand what you really want to do. However, and for example: `result[0].hasOwnProperty("6")` will check if the object related to `result[0]` have a property name `"6"`. Check documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)